# where is the attribute android:titleCondensed applicable in menu

Tags: android

Can anybody please explain me about this? I couldn't find sufficient information in developer documentation.
Is it also applicable when item is shown as action and long clicked on icon shows a toast containing title.

Comment: it's not applicable when item is not shown as action, title is shown as marquee instead of using titleCondensed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short: it shows up when space is nice to be kept.

I took pictures on Galaxy S4 4.4.2.

The first picture is a landscape, having only three selection related icons, you can see that the condensed title is used there:
[image]
however if I don't supply the the `titleCondensed` it uses `title` and it clearly fits:
[image]

The full `title` is used at any other places where space is not an issue, like the "tooltip" (long press on an action bar icon, internally called [cheat sheet](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#L273)) or the overflow menu:
[image]

... and here's part of code I used (with `appcompat-v7`):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Possibly more items like "Edit Item" and "Delete Item" below -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_select_all"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_select_all"
        android:title="Select All"
        android:titleCondensed="All"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <!-- Same for Select None <-> None -->
    <!-- Same for Invert Selection <-> Invert -->
</menu>
```

All of the above is empirical observation, and hence probably incomplete, but I was curious, so here are the Android code points implementing the below:
*Note the `internal` package and these are from the framework not the support library!*

- [`MenuItemImpl.getTitleForItemView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/MenuItemImpl.java#L343) returns the title based on `prefersCondensedTitle`, which has three implementations:

  1. Action Bar icon and text: [`ActionMenuItemView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#L153): `true`
  2. Action Bar overflow probably: [`ListMenuItemView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ListMenuItemView.java#L263): `false`
  3. Old style Options Menu: [`IconMenuItemView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/IconMenuItemView.java#L312): `true`

Comment: These empirical examples are so much more valuable than any Android docs. You would assume that `titleCondensed` would _only_ be used when there isn't enough space to use the regular `title`, but nope, that's not the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Simply put, the titleCondensed is the title you would like to show when the title string is too long for the device it's being showed on.